# How to fix Get method for POST in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, url

I wrote code(shown below) in .htaccess, for remove index.php on URL, but when i click any links on my website, URL shows GET parameters, so how can i change it to POST?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.(php|html|htm)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\z
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rocketfirm.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `R=301` means an external redirect with status code 301, browsers follow that by issuing a GET request for the new location. 307 would force the browser to repeat the POST request instead - not sure though if that is really what you want (because you kinda failed to describe what actual problem you are trying to solve here), because that would force the client to send all that data a second time. So unless you want to redirect a POST request to a different domain, it should probably rather be just an _internal_ redirect to begin with.

Comment: when i click any links on my website, URL it used to show rocketfirm.com/business.html, and now show rocketfirm.com/php?login=&name=business, so how can I return to the starting position?

Comment: What is that supposed to have to do with the POST redirect problem? Feels like a completely different question - and is still about as unclear as what you asked initially. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question, to include a proper description of what problem you are actually trying to solve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of this problem, put this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

it's remove index.php from URL and save post parameters